# How to use slick slider current slide as dom?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slick.js

I know there are many question similar to this but I can't figure out what is the correct method to access current slide as dom to modify with jquery?
As already discussed in this forum

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/411

$(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide))); is one method to access it.
but slick already add slick-active class to current slide.So some people are suggesting to use as $('.slick-active')

What is the correct method from both?
Sorry for not commenting code as I am asking question from mobile site.

Comment: Share the relevant html

Comment: I just want to know current slide selector.I have long html in my pc.